# What is the difference between the Joule and Joule–Thomson coefficients?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

Is there a difference between the Joule coefficient and the Joule–Thomson coefficient? Also, I am having a hard time understanding what they mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Joule coefficient is $$\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_U$$

Experimentally, Joule attempted to measure this value by expanding gas into an evacuated, insulated container, thus ensuring $U$ is constant.

The [Joule–Thomson coefficient](http://tccc.iesl.forth.gr/education/local/Labs-PC-II/JT.pdf) is $$\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right)_H$$

Experimentally, this is realized by expanding a flow of gas in an insulted pipe from a high pressure upstream region to a lower pressure downstream region, the two regions being seperated by a porous frit.

For more information see [THE JOULE AND JOULE-THOMSON EXPERIMENTS](http://astrowww.phys.uvic.ca/~tatum/thermod/thermod10.pdf) by Dr. J. B. Tatum, University of Victoria.

Comment: So, the Joule coefficient is a ratio of the change in temperature to the change in volume with constant internal energy, and the Joule-Thomson coefficient is a ratio of the change in temperature to the change in pressure under constant enthalpy? In the Joule experiment, the gas does no work, and the temperature doesn't change?

Comment: This almost correct, only your statement "the temperature doesn't change" is incorrect.  Joule didn't detect a temperature change, because his equipment wasn't good enough, but for a real gas (not an ideal gas) there is a temperature change.